# JavaFX jar runs on my machine but doesn't run on others

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, java-native-interface

I have built a JavaFX application in IntelliJ with SDK corretto 15 and openjfx-17.0.0.1 and when I run it on my machine it works fine, however when it runs on other machines I get the error

"Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again"

Please let me know if there's any more information you need. Thanks!

Comment: At two potential reasons for this: (1) The target computer does not have JavaFX installed; (2) You're including JavaFX in your application, but the target computer is a different platform (e.g. Linux vs Windows; JavaFX has platform-specific native code).

Comment: Can you run the JAR from the command line? What is the exact error, there?

Comment: I suggest you research jpackage use for JavaFX. Package your app for distribution using FXPackageScript as a template (if using maven) or badass jlink (if using gradle). Use maven or gradle if not using either.  The output will be a native installer for the target OS which has no dependencies, so users can easily install or uninstall your app on their system using the app management features of the OS which they are already used to using, and the app will always execute reliably.